# Unable to append data in PDF using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox and trying to append data(Highlight,Draw Image, etc.) in a PDF. I've noticed that when I use *document.getPage(0)*, it doesn't append the data. But when I use *document.addPage()* it adds the data but in a new page. I want to add the data in an existing page. This is the code that I'm using.

```
File file = new File("FinalPDF 1.pdf");
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load( new File(file) );
PDPage page1 = document.getPage(0);
PDPageContentStream stream1 = new PDPageContentStream(document, page1, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("download.jpg",document); 
stream1.drawImage(pdImage, 250,200);
stream1.close();
document1.save(file);
document1.close();
```

I tried 'PDAnnotation' and 'PDAnnotationTextMarkup' for highlighting but it still doesn't work.

Uploaded the two PDFs below.

1. document.getPage(0) - PDF 1.pdf
2. document.addPage - FinalPDF 1.pdf

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a4e9659711a101403d25ba549a7ff78b20230327104217/19fa30

Comment: As you're drawing on an existing page, have you made sure that your coordinates 250, 200 are in the visible page area? Also you use the same file name for reading and writing; please try to save the result in a different file.

Comment: Yes. when I try the same coordinates using '.addPage' it adds the image in the visible page area. I tried saving in a different file as well. It's still the same.

Comment: *"when I try the same coordinates using '.addPage' it adds the image in the visible page area."* - a new page created by PDFBox usually has a matching coordinate system. But an arbitrary file you loaded may have a completely different one. For that reason I asked whether you are sure that your coordinates are in the visible area of the exact page you loaded...

Comment: Yes. I tried different combinations of coordinates. Even fetched coordinates of a particular text on a page and tried adding the image/highlight there. The page remains unchanged.

Comment: Can you share your test pdf after adding the image to an existing page?

Comment: I've added the screenshots on the question.

Comment: Can you share your test _pdf_ after adding the image to an existing page?

Comment: Can't see an option to attach files. I joined stackoverflow just yesterday. Don't even have a reputation enough to start a chat

Comment: Upload the file to a sharehoster, then edit your question and include the link.

Comment: Uploaded the PDFs

Comment: The media box of the first page of your document is `[ 0 0 792 -612 ]`. Thus, your coordinates 250, 200 are **not** in the visible page area of that page. That been said, though, in "PDF 1.pdf" nothing appears to have been added which does not really match your code. Which PDFBox version have you used your code with?

Comment: Giving the Y Coordinate as negative worked! How do I find these media box coordinates? I only knew that the Y coordinate needs a negative value after you gave the media box for the page.

Comment: Use PDFDebugger to see them, or call getMediaBox() on the PDPage object.